# Can usort() work for an object?

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> ErrorException: Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

I am passing an Object of results from an SQL query into usort:

```
usort($results, array($this, "sortDistance"));
```

My Sort Function:

```
private function sortDistance ($first, $next)
{
    $d1 = $this->searchDistance[$first->zip];
    $d2 = $this->searchDistance[$next->zip];

    if ($d1 == $d2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($d1 > $d2) ? +1 : -1;
}
```

Is there another way to sort an object based on its properties?

Comment: Read the error message again. Only sequences (read: an array) can be sorted with the [\*sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function. It is not talking about the values *in* the array.

Comment: What is "object of results"?

Comment: If you use object attributes only you can cast the object as array, sort it and then cast it as object again

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of objects from your result set, where the object has the properties you need to sort by. then use member function as usort's callback